# Browser native scroll function: how to check compatibility

Tags: javascript

The function [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#Browser_Compatibility) in "most" browsers can be used, but it seems that it can be "overloaded". From the compatibility tab, you'll see that some browsers support

`element.scroll(scrollToOptions)`
whereas others only support
`element.scroll(x, y)`

How can I check which method is supported (despite it having the same name) in the current browser?

Comment: You can also use [Intersection Observer if it's applicable.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) This is not overloading the scroll function and was implemented to overcome this issue. it can't be used for everything where scroll was used, but where it makes sense it should be used over listening for scroll function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var isSmoothScrollSupported = 'scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style;

var scrollToOptions = {
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
}; 

if (isSmoothScrollSupported) {
    // Native smooth scrolling
    window.scroll(scrollToOptions);
} else {
    // Old way scrolling without effects
    window.scroll(scrollToOptions.left, scrollToOptions.top);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it in a few browsers and it seems to work. Where can I read more about this scrollBehavior property and how sure can I be that there are not browsers that might not support smooth scroll, but still have scrollBehavior implemented?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions#Properties

MDN say that browser support ScrollToOptions with smooth, etc or not support it at all

Comment: Lovely. Thank you. This got me out of a hole with Chrome on older Samsung tablets.